# Checking if a user has been assigned a token in Django Restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I am setting up token authentication for a site using Django Restframework and need to be able to have a user download their token, however the catch is that they much only be able to download their token once (similar to the Amazon AWS model).

In other words; is there a native way to check if a user has been assigned a token in restframework?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried poking through the documentation to see if there are any other Token.object functions other than create and get_or_create, but wasn't able to find anything. Source diving didn't give me anything either. 

My goal is to avoid a try catch block for a failed token authorization in favor of a native solution (too many possible problems with the try-catch block approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.conf import settings
token = Token.objects.create(user=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

now you can just check if your given user has a token:

```
user_with_token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
```

if you just wanna see if the user has a token:

```
is_tokened = Token.objects.filter(user=user).exist()  # Returns a boolean
```

if the entry exists it means the user has a token assigned to it.
Reference: [HERE](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

Follow the documentation there to make sure your database is migrated.

Comment: So to check this I run in a shell;
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token;
from django.conf import settings;
#I've created a user test which has no token in django web admin;
u = User.objects.get(username='test');
user_token = Token.objects.get(user=u);
< This returns a DoesNotExist Error, which I'm trying to essentially catch natively

Answer (score 0):

try use a django signal to create user token automatically, something like this on your models file.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
if created:
    Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```